# Bootstrap inline 2 form with labels above input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with responsive design. So i have components:

[image]

Here is code:

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7 pull-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>City</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Postal code</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7 pull-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Street</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>House</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The problem is when i change size of window - i have this ugly destroyed design:

[image]

How i can fix it? (only bootstrap if it's possible)

**UPDATE**

Using advices i've add pull-left to all columns and everything is okay.

[image]

But when i little bit ensmall size there are result:
[image]

Comment: What's the window size when that UI starts to occur?

Comment: weidth = 990px.

Comment: You might need to tell us what the expected result should be. Should each input be on it's own row (i.e. 4 rows of inputs)? Or should the two inputs per row be maintained at all sizes?

Comment: When you enlarge, or ensmall? (that wasn't English..sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a guess right now, not sure if you want the form items to reflow or not. What is the expected result? Should each input be on it's own row (i.e. 4 rows of inputs)? Or should the two inputs per row be maintained at all sizes?

Here is an answer to place each input on their own row at the breakpoint.

Remove `.pull-left` from the first column in each row.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Postal code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Street</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>House</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a solution for maintaining two inputs per row. You need to use a different column class. Currently you're using the medium `-md-` class. Here I have used the extra small `-xs-` class. See [Bootstrap Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) for different column classes.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Postal code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Street</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>House</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need add the "pull-left" to all the column `<div>` tags  like mentioned below:

```
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7 pull-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>City</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 pull-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Postal code</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7 pull-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Street</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 pull-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>House</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I and able to get decent result.

Comment: Using different column classes (i.e. `col-xs`) is more appropriate than permanently floating those columns to the left with `pull-left`. Not only that, using `.pull-left` doesn't respect the column sizes of **col-md-7** and **col-md-5**.

Comment: Nice, it's work, but it's create another problem, i will update my question